# How can detect too high class coupling using SonarQube with c# plugin 4.0

Tags: c#, plugins, sonarqube

I'm using SonarQube to improve our c# code quality.
I've defined a quality profile with the rule: "Class should not be coupled to too many other classes (csharpsquid:ClassCoupling)". However, since the version 3.4 of the c# plugin, this rule has been dropped. I can understand that this rule is controversial, however, it can indicate that a class has too many responsibilities. Even so, it is vague, the developer can still mark the issue as a false positive. Moreover it's possible to set a threshold beyond which a violation is detected. I think it would be better to leave the freedom to add or not this rule in a quality profile, rather than have it simply removed from the list. The only other rules that I found to replace it are: CA1505: Avoid unmaintainable code (fxcop:AvoidUnmantainableCode) and CA1506: Avoid excessive class coupling (fxcop:AvoidExcessiveClassCoupling). I don't think that is more clear or less vague. So, are there any other alternatives that I can use to measure the class coupling?

Answer (score 0):

I know that this decision is a bit opinionated but on our side we've decided that each issue generated by a rule should almost never lead to a controversial discussion to determine if the issue is a false-positive or not according to the context. Even if this rule "csharpsquid:ClassCoupling" might sound useful, in practise it was generating too many false-positives from an end-user point of view, so we decided to simply drop it. See https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SONARCS-464.